# How to track down why code behaves differently with optimization flags

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, valgrind

so I have some complex C code that encodes and decodes bit arrays with error correction.  The code was based on [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjHuraH8OXJAhUBw2MKHcvYDcgQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eccpage.com%2Fbch3.c&usg=AFQjCNFop7fuAAT4R961PNPrROp_Rt9Qww&bvm=bv.110151844,d.cGc), and patched to meet my needs (so it really doesn't function the same as the linked code, except in its core).

With optimizations off, I get what I expect on the output.  With optimizations on full (ie, -O3 provided during gcc compilation), the code behaves differently.

I'm trying to figure out what I should be looking for to track this down; as in is there something obvious that the optimizations do that I can look for before I start adding `printf`s everywhere in the code to see in which line(s) the output differs between optimizations.

A clue, I think, is that when I run the code through valgrind, without optimizations, I get no errors or warnings:

```
==5112== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5112== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5112== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5112== Command: ./a.out
==5112== 
!!!!! decode ret = 0 (my output)
Nid decoded = 0010100100111010101110101001001110111110110000100110101000101011 (my output)
==5112== 
==5112== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5112==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5112==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==5112== 
==5112== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5112== 
==5112== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5112== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

With optimizations enabled and --track-origins=yes, valgrind reports the following:

```
==5506== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5506== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5506== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5506== Command: ./a.out
==5506== 
==5506== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5506==    at 0x400DC1: bch_decode (in /home/directory/bch/a.out)
==5506==    by 0x4005CD: main (in /home/directory/bch/a.out)
==5506==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==5506==    at 0x40094B: bch_decode (in /home/directory/bch/a.out)
==5506== 
==5506== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5506==    at 0x400DC3: bch_decode (in /home/directory/bch/a.out)
==5506==    by 0x4005CD: main (in /home/directory/bch/a.out)
==5506==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==5506==    at 0x40094B: bch_decode (in /home/directory/bch/a.out)
==5506== 
!!!!! decode ret = -1
Nid decoded = 0010100100111010101110101001001110111110110000100010101000101011
==5506== 
==5506== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5506==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5506==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==5506== 
==5506== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5506== 
==5506== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5506== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

However, with optimizations on, I don't think Valgrind can tell me specific line numbers, or variables in which this happens.  Even if I were to step through the code with GDB, it will be hard to nail this down because of the optimizations.

Is there a way I can sort this out, maybe /emulate/ the behavior of optimizations, but keep the correct line numbers and variable names in the debug information (unlikely from everything I've so far read).

Any help to move this forward even a little bit would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless the compiler generates invalid code, such problems are often an indicator of exploiting undefined behaviour.  (Bets are on the latter.) Check your code agains [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) violations.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] and add all required information **in** the question (not just links, no images).

Comment: What @Olaf said, plus if you are going to use compiler optimisation, set the warnings level up high, and treat all warnings as errors.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  The question is not "where in my code is this happening.", it's "what steps can I take next to track down differences between behavior of code that has been optimized vs non-optimized.  Commenting on everyone's question with "Provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and add all required information in the question (not just links, no images)." is non productive.

Comment: @Clifford `-Wall, -Wextra`, the only warnings are array subscripts are of type `char`.  Are there additional warning outputs I can enable?  Can you enlighten me here?

Comment: Add `-Wconversion` at least, others might also be useful. And cast only **iff** you understand and accept **all** implications.

Comment: @Olaf.  Hey, I narrowed down the problem.  By adding dumb printf's, I've got the code to bahave the same way (the correct way) with optimizations on or off.  If I provide a MCV example, would you be willing to take a look at it, or should I post it as a new question?

Comment: `printf()` uses a considerable amount of stack, so the memory used by some later declared but uninitialized local variable may have been modified by a previous printf call in such a way that the code appears to work (by dumb luck) when the variable is accessed.  Any change of code such as insertion or deletion of code, or change of code generation options may affect the program's behaviour.  Often optimisation settings cause uninitialised data warnings detected due to the abstract execution analysis used by the optimiser.  The printf may not even be in the same function as the error.

Comment: @justynnuff "Provide a MCVE" is the best way to get a good answer to your question. It's also a good way to solve the problem on your own.  The only way it would be "non-productive" is if you are too lazy.

Answer (score 1):

valgrind tells you that you have uninitialized variables:

```
==5506== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5506==    at 0x400DC1: bch_decode (in /home/directory/bch/a.out)
==5506==    by 0x4005CD: main (in /home/directory/bch/a.out)
==5506==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==5506==    at 0x40094B: bch_decode (in /home/directory/bch/a.out)
==5506== 
==5506== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5506==    at 0x400DC3: bch_decode (in /home/directory/bch/a.out)
==5506==    by 0x4005CD: main (in /home/directory/bch/a.out)
==5506==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==5506==    at 0x40094B: bch_decode (in /home/directory/bch/a.out)
```

Recompile and re-link your code with `-g` flag to see line numbers in valgrind output.

Comment: Will those line numbers be accurate with optimizations on?

Comment: @justynnuff Not necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - use any static analysis tools available, starting with the maximum warning level available on your compiler of choice. Sometimes using a *different* compiler (e.g. llvm) may produce new warnings the first one didn't give you.

Valgrind says you have uninitialized variable trouble, so "gcc -Wall" will probably nail it.

Step 2 - try valgrind on code built -g; maybe you'll get line numbers. (Or maybe it'll stop replicating, because of interaction of -g with -O.)

Step 3a - intense code review, looking for undefined behaviour. How well do you understand "sequence points" in C?

If there is any multithreading, signal handling, etc. then look for ordering issues. (Unlikely with the stated purpose of the code, but a common source of optimizer-related breakage.)

Step 3b - examine the assembly code generated in both instances. Consider stepping code with the debugger at the assembly level rather than the source code level.

Step 3c - enable/disable individual optimizations, and see which one breaks things. Then use understanding of what that optimization does to guide code review

Step 3d - simplify your code. The oversight may appear as a result of this exercise. And if not, you can start calling individual parts of it, and checking which bits are misbehaving. (Odds are once you are looking at the right lines, you'll see what's wrong.)